# ¿Cómo pasar datos que se encuentra en la BD a través del controlador a la vista?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

**Método (Datos) de mi Controlador:**

```
// GET: datos
    public ActionResult Datos()
    {
        var datos = db.alumno.Include(a => a.grupo);
        ViewBag.mensaje = "HOLA MUNDO";

        var query = from Alumno in db.alumno
                    join Grupo in db.grupo on Alumno.id_alumno equals Grupo.id_alumno
                    select new { alumno = Alumno, grupo = Grupo };

        return View(query); 

    }
```

**Vista donde se deben de mostrar los datos**

```html
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication1.grupo>
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Datos</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div> 

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            @item.id_grupo <br />
        }

        @ViewBag.mensaje
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tu variable `datos` es una lista o colección de objetos del tipo `Alumno`, lo que debes hacer es:

```
var datos = db.alumno.Include(a => a.grupo);
return View(datos);
```

Y en tu View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Project.Models.Alumno>
```

Para recorrerlos:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    //item.Nombre
    //etc
}
```

**EDICION**

Respecto a que cambiaste la consulta te ayudo

Como ahora no devuelves una lista de un objeto en concreto si no que una lista con JOIN. Debes hacer lo siguiente :

Crear un MODELO

```
public class AlumnoGrupo
{
    public string AlumnoNombre { get; set; }
    public string GrupoNombre { get; set; }
    public int GrupoId { get; set; }
}
```

Luego en tu Controller :

```
List<AlumnoGrupo> model = new List<AlumnoGrupo>();
var result = from a in db.alumno join g in db.grupo on a.id_alumno equals g.id_alumno
             select new AlumnoGrupo()
             { 
                AlumnoNombre = a.Nombre,
                GrupoNombre = g.Nombre,
                GrupoId = g.Id
             }
model = result.ToList();
return View(model);
```

*En este bloque de codigo del Join, creamos nuestro objeto con los atributos que necesitemos, yo hice esos campos para darte un ejemplo y ademas porque no conozco los datos que tu necesitas.*

Y finalmente en tu View

```
@model IEnumerable<Project.Models.AlumnoGrupo>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @item.GrupoId <br />
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias ya quedo

Comment: cree un JOIN con LINQ para traer los datos pero me esta marcando error

Comment: listo ya actualize el codigo

Comment: disculpa, apenas estoy aprendiendo

Comment: Claro deja imprimo los errores

Comment: @Javierfr actualice mi respuesta, cuentame como te va

Comment: Hola y como creo un modelo

Comment: En tu carpeta Models, creas el modelo tal como te lo deje yo en mi respuesta @Javierfr

Comment: esque en la carpeta no me dice crear modelo, solo me marca agregar nuevo controlador o agregar nuevoelemento

Comment: si tengo la carpeta pero no me dice agregar nuevo modelo, como por ejemplo cuando quiero un controlador si me dice agregar nuevo controlador

Comment: Debes agregar una nueva clase!

Comment: OK, gracias dela lo intento

Comment: @siesi ya quedo!!!!

Comment: me alegro @Javierfr ! saludos

Answer (score 3):

Actualiza tu código de la siguiente forma:

**Controlador**

```
// GET: datos
public ActionResult Datos()
{
    var datos = db.alumno.Include(a => a.grupo);
    ViewBag.mensaje = "HOLA MUNDO";
    return View(datos);
}
```

**Vista (en caso que `datos` no sea una colección)**

```
@model MiProyecto.Alumno      
@{

    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Datos</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div> 
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Nombre)
        @ViewBag.mensaje
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Vista (en caso que `datos` sea una colección)**

```
@model IEnumerable<MiProyecto.Alumno>      
@{

    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Datos</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div> 
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
             @item.Nombre <br/>
        }
        @ViewBag.mensaje
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: muchas gracias por la ayuda